# Why does nested fadeOut not work if used on the same element that is the outermost fadeIn statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me why the `$("#opening-first").fadeOut()` line of this is not executing??

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#opening-first").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000, function() {
    $("#opening-second").fadeIn(1000, function() {
     $("#opening-first").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $("#body-overlay").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
     });
    });
  });
});
```

It seems as if this should be pretty straightforward. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="body-overlay">
  <div class="centered">
      <h1 id="opening-first">My name is Trevor Hinesley.</h1>
          <p class="medium" id="opening-second">And I like creating.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working simply because of the first delay. You see, the second parameter of `delay()` should be a string for a queue name. You can reuse that queue name with the function `stop()` or any other method using a "queue" but it doesnt matter since it's not what you are doing here.

If you want to delay the second fadeIn, your code should look like that :

```
$("#opening-first").fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $("#opening-second").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $("#opening-first").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $("#body-overlay").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rk4Bz/